# How JVM manages memory for methods?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, static, jvm

For example we have an instance of `MyClass` and it contains 1 method. This method should be kept in memory. When this instance of `MyClass` is being GC'ed, is a reference to this method being deleted as well? I want to figure out weather doing everything via Dependency Injection (hence creating new instances of every class) requires less memory and more efficient or simple `Helper` classes with a bunch of static methods are still good.

Comment: Dependency injection will not make the application use significantly more or less memory, so saving memory is not a good reason to use DI.

Comment: The method code is kept with the class, not with the instance.

Comment: @Jesper, I pretty much understand it but I just had an argument about this and honestly, I just wanted something to prove my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance methods of an object are stored in its class object (only one copy should exist), they are not "copied" with each new instance, instead, under the hood each instance holds a reference to the method implementation residing in the class object.
Instances are garbage collected not the class data. The class data gets stored in permgen space or metaspace depending on the java version.
Garbage collectors work specifically on the heap where the instances are created not on the permgen or metaspace.

Comment: Under the hood each instance holds a reference to the *class,* which in turn holds references to all its methods.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne
So, there is that meta-space that keeps references to all the methods and it doesn't really matter if there is an instance of the class that contains some method or not, right? So, it is preferable to use static methods if you don't an instance of a class?

Comment: @VictorK. static methods are also stored in metaspace but static methods cannot use instance variables so u cannot make all your methods static because they wont be able to utilize instance data. But yes if u want to access only static data in the method the method itself needs to be static.